# How to get attr which contains "_" in name?

Tags: json, ember.js

I have something like this in my model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  something: DS.attr(),
  something_else: DS.attr()
});
```

and like this in my template:

```
{{model.something}}
{{model.something_else}}
```

I use JSON in fixtures and it looks like:

```
[ { 
"something": "abc",
"something_else": "cba" 
} ]
```

In inspector i see correct something_else in object, but it doesn't show the value on api.

Comment: There is no reason this should not work, so something else must be going on. As a starting point for tracking down the problem, you might want to look at the model instance in Ember Inspector. For example, the server might not be returning `something_else` in the payload, or it might be being mapped to `somethingElse` by an adapter. By the way, please don't ask questions which say "doesn't work". Please give a specific description of the undesired/unexpected behavior. Does it not output anything; does it results in a JS error, does your computer crash---what?

Comment: I didn't mention that i use JSON in fixtures and it looks like:

`[
  {
    "something": "abc",
    "something_else": "cba"
  }
]`

In inspector i see correct something_else in object, but it doesn't show the value on api.